# is there any way I can split the hashes in an array?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash, scripting

I have been trying to split an array with hashes  but I am getting the following error

> "use of uninitialised value $_ in split"

```
@array = (("forest:k233356"),("wi45one:1onetothree"));
foreach(@array)
   ($id,$pwd)=split(":",$_);
```

From the following code, I am not able to split the array and assign the following to `$id` and `$pwd`. Any leads will be appreciated!!

Comment: Those are not hashed. They are strings. try `($id,$pwd)=split(/:/);`

Comment: 1) The code you posted does not produce the message you claim it does. It doesn't even compile. 2) If you add the curlies that are needed for your code to compile, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is:

```
@array = ("forest:k233356", "wi45one:1onetothree");
%hash = map {split(":",$_, 2) } @array;
```

`@array` is an array of strings here. The `map` applies `split ":", $_,2` on each element of the array, this splits each string into at most 2 fields (as mentioned in a comment below) and returns the results to `%hash`. In the end, the `%hash` will have `id`s as keys and `pwd`s as values.

If you want more help you can read:

1. https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors
2. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html
3. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: You want that third argument of split to ensure you get two elements: `split /:/, $_, 2`. Otherwise, some strings might give 1 or more than two elements, and that messes up the assignment to `%hash`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact that your code didn't compile (and, therefore, can't have possibly given the error message that you show us) it was very close to the correct answer.

This is lightly cleaned up and extended (to actually put the data into the hash) but it's pretty similar to what you started with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my @array = ("forest:k233356", "wi45one:1onetothree");

foreach (@array) {
  my ($id, $pwd) = split(/:/, $_, 2);

  $hash{$id} = $pwd;
}

say Dumper \%hash;
```

A few stylistic points:

1. I added a bit more whitespace in various places.
2. I removed the unnecessary parentheses where you define your array.
3. I made the first argument to `split()` into a regular expression.
4. I added `2` as the third argument to `split()` so the string is only ever split into two parts (it makes no difference with your existing data - but it's good to be safe).

None of these would have made any difference to the way your code worked - they just make your code that bit easier to read and understand.